# Sending Serializable objects via a Tibco JMS throws a Deserialization failed error

Tags: java, serialization, jms, tibco

I have a java application that sends a simple java bean over JMS to another java application.

This work completely fine ActiveMQ, but when I switch to Tibco JMS Broker an error is thrown on the receiving application. The bean implements the *Serializable* interface, and both application are running from the same jars which contains the class for the bean.

I start Tibco JMS using *tibjmsd.exe*. The version is 4.1.0.

A simple check from within the sending java client generates the error below:

Code:

```
..
....
MyBean bean = new MyBean(1,”Test”);
final ObjectMessage msg = jmssession.createObjectMessage(bean);
    try {
        msg.getObject();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        LOG.error("Problem with storing bean", e);
    }
....
..
```

The error message from the above code:

```
javax.jms.MessageFormatException: Deserialization failed: [Ljava.lang.String;
     at com.tibco.tibjms.TibjmsObjectMessage.getObject(TibjmsObjectMessage.java:199)
```

The same code work without error running a ActiveMQ
Is there something i can do or check ?

Comment: The sending application uses which implementation of JMS

Comment: The sending application uses the Client Tibco Jars. Connection is made via a generic JMS implementation, i.e. Context.lookup connection factory, get connection, etc.

Comment: Further investigation has found that the error "Deserialization" occurs when the javabean has an primitive array (i.e. String[]). Changing to a List<String> fixes the problem, BUT is this really the case, Tibco can not accept Objects that contain Primitive Arrays ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you need to find out the `linkedException` for that `JMSException`

```
catch(MessageFormatException mfe)
{
      mfe.printStackTrace(); // what you told us
      mfe.getLinkedException().printStackTrace(); // the interesting one
}
```

I have the feeling this will be related to their `TibjmsObjectMessage$CLOIS.resolveClass` inability to parse classnames correctly for native arrays.

It seems that some are having trouble to have even a simple `long` in their message:
https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-1231?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:worklog-tabpanel

And a suggested solution, which would work, is to serialize the object yourself and use `javax.jms.BytesMessage`.